# How to use a cookie to save the clicked value grab the cookie every time the user opens the page

Tags: javascript, php

I have following code to highlight table record with three different colors when user click a checkbox. How can I use a `cookie` to save the clicked value with  grab the `cookie` every time the user opens the page everytime? I haven't no idea how `cookies` are used. Answer would be really appreciate

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<style>
.highlight-red {
    background-color: red;
}    
.highlight-green {
    background-color: green;
}
.highlight-yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
}    
</style>
<div class="col-lg-10">
    <table id="Table" border="1">
        <tr class="highlight">
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="cb1" id="cb1" value="y" onChange="changeSoma(this, 'red')" /></td>
        <td>Click me</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="cb2" id="cb2" value="y" onChange="changeSoma(this, 'green')" /></td>
        <td>Click me</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="cb3" id="cb3" value="y" onChange="changeSoma(this, 'yellow')" /></td>
        <td>Click me</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    function changeSoma(data, color){
            if(data.checked && color == 'red'){
                $(data).parent().parent().addClass("highlight-red");
            }
            else{
                $(data).parent().parent().removeClass("highlight-red");
            }
            if(data.checked && color == 'green'){
                $(data).parent().parent().addClass("highlight-green");
            }
            else{
                $(data).parent().parent().removeClass("highlight-green");
            }
            if(data.checked && color == 'yellow'){
                $(data).parent().parent().addClass("highlight-yellow");
            }
            else{
                $(data).parent().parent().removeClass("highlight-yellow");
            }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`localStorage` is easier than cookie I thought . You can set and get by `localStorage.setItem or localStorage.getItem` and it will remain until you remove them !!!

```
<script>

    var cond = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("check"));
    for(var i in cond) {
        if(cond[i]) {
         $("#"+i).attr("checked",true);
         $("#"+i).parent().parent().addClass("highlight-"+cond[i]);
        }
    }
    function changeSoma(data, color){
            var state;
            if(localStorage.getItem("check") == null) {
                state = {cb1:0,cb2:0,cb3:0};
            } else{
                state = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("check"));
            }

            if(data.checked) {
                $(data).parent().parent().addClass("highlight-"+color);
                state[data.id]= color;
            } else {
                $(data).parent().parent().removeClass("highlight-"+color);
                state[data.id]= 0;
            }
            localStorage.setItem("check",JSON.stringify(state));
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mr.David JorHpan. It worked well and I was trying with this for 2 days. Thank you very much.

Comment: My pleasure to help you

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the values to be selected still even when the user goes to a different page on your site and then select them again once back in that page.

As stated [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp), you set the cookies using the `document.cookie` javascript property.

The property mentioned above, however, is a semicolon separated key-value pair. you'll have to manipulate the string in order to add/edit a value.

Once you've added the value that you want, you can once again read it and then set the rows you want to be selected.

To get the selected value, you could use `$(data).val()` and put it inside `changeSoma()`. From there, you could check if it's checked `$(data).is(':checked')`. If it's checked, add it to `document.cookie` like `document.cookie = "key=value; key2=value2;"`

Comment: How can I save the clicked value Mr.Bobby?

Answer (score 0):

it easier using `localStorage` but since you're using jQuery then use [jQuery cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) plugin

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <style>
    .highlight-red {
      background-color: red;
    }

    .highlight-green {
      background-color: green;
    }

    .highlight-yellow {
      background-color: yellow;
    }

  </style>
  <div class="col-lg-10">
    <table id="Table" border="1">
      <tr class="highlight">
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="cb1" id="cb1" value="y" onChange="changeSoma(this, 'red')" /></td>
        <td>Click me</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="cb2" id="cb2" value="y" onChange="changeSoma(this, 'green')" /></td>
        <td>Click me</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="cb3" id="cb3" value="y" onChange="changeSoma(this, 'yellow')" /></td>
        <td>Click me</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var checkedBox = $.cookie('checkedBox');
      console.log(checkedBox);
      if(checkedBox !== undefined) {
        // to check only
        //$(checkedBox).attr('checked', true);
        // emulate click to check and change the class
        $(checkedBox).each(function() {
          this.click();
        })
      }

    })

    function changeSoma(data, color) {
      if(data.checked && color == 'red') {
        $(data).parent().parent().addClass("highlight-red");
      }
      else {
        $(data).parent().parent().removeClass("highlight-red");
      }
      if(data.checked && color == 'green') {
        $(data).parent().parent().addClass("highlight-green");
      }
      else {
        $(data).parent().parent().removeClass("highlight-green");
      }
      if(data.checked && color == 'yellow') {
        $(data).parent().parent().addClass("highlight-yellow");
      }
      else {
        $(data).parent().parent().removeClass("highlight-yellow");
      }
      // set cookie
      var checked = "";
      $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
        if($(this).prop('checked')) {
          checked += "#" + this.id + ","; // #cb, jQuery id selector
        }
      })

      checked = checked.replace(/,$/, '')
      console.log(checked);
      $.cookie('checkedBox', checked);
    }

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort Mr.ewwink.But this code neither highlight record nor stay the result after page refreshing